# Django test runner failing with "relation does not exist" error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm seeing an error when running my tests, i.e. `$ ./manage.py test --settings=my.test.settings`
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "<relation name>" does not exist`

This is after running `./manage.py makemigrations && migrate`.

Answer (score 9):

This error turns out (usually) to be caused, ultimately, by failing to create the initial migration for a new app. the error was resolved by running `$ ./manage.py makemigrations <my new app module name> && migrate`

**NOTE: `makemigrations` *DOES NOT* AUTOMATICALLY CREATE THE INITIAL MIGRATION FOR NEW APPS**

Comment: `makemigrations` should create the initial migration for new apps, especifically if the new app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me because I was trying to run a piece of code that accessed the database when Django starts.

```py
# file name: blog/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def ready(self):
        from .business import markdown_to_html
        markdown_to_html.refresh_posts() # This method access the database.
```

Then, when I executed the tests: `python manage.py test`, this code fragment was executed and I got the error you mentioned.

Why? It is explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

As I needed to execute this method only once, I decided to create a management command.

Here is the code:

```py
# file name: md_to_html.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from blog.business import markdown_to_html


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Convert posts written in markdown to html'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        markdown_to_html.refresh_posts()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('HTML files created'))
```

Before starting the Django project, I executed the command using the following line: `python manage.py md_to_html`. In this way I ensured this code is executed only once in a safely.

Now when I run the tests I don't get the error anymore.

Here you can find more information about how to create a custom management command in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

This link describes how to test a custom management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-management-commands

Answer (score 0):

In case you faced this issue while using pytest-django package, check that your haven't created new migrations with `--reuse-db` option in your `pytest.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, table wasn't created just for one model and i figured out that the model is placed in models directory and is not added to `models/__init__.py`. Just added it to `__init__.py` and magic happened.

models tree looks like:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    model.py
```

model.py

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    pass
```

`__init__.py`

```
from .model import ModelName

__all__ = [
    'ModelName',
]
```